# Trouble running openCV samples on android eclipse emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

Where do I even start...

I'm trying to do static initialization for openCV so that I can run ANY OF THE SAMPLES that I have with opencv library 2.4.8

I've followed the steps as outlined [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android), and I've become familiar with the NDK setup.

Yet still, when I run, say, Puzzle15 sample, the emulated program immediately asks "OpenCV Manager Package was not found. Try to install it?"

Someone please help me get this working. I'm new to both Android and openCV, but it's very important to me to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use This code for solve your problem :

```
 <path_to_your_sdk_folder>/platform-tools/adb.exe install OpenCV-2.4.5-android-  sdk/apk/OpenCV_2.4.5_Manager_2.7_<platform>.apk
```

of course insert this code to 'cmd' in windows 

also you can see this page :[install  manually using adb tool](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/android/service/doc/UseCases.html#how-to-select-the-proper-version-of-opencv-manager)

Comment: Thank you, I'm running through it now.